# Null Pointer exception in ejb 2.0 while referring a local beans home interface

Tags: ejb, ejb-2.x

I am just trying out examples of entity beans. I am using JBOSS 4.0.0, EJB 2.0, MyEclipse 8.6. Reason for using JBOSS 4.0.0 and EJB 2.0 is just for learning sake. I am reading head first book. In the process help me if I made any mistakes. I wrote a build file using ant to deploy this in deploy directory of JBOSS. Don't know where I went wrong, but struggling with error. I am getting this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.LocalHomeProxy.invoke(LocalHomeProxy.java:118)
at $Proxy0.findByPrimaryKey(Unknown Source)
at AccesesPackage.DirectorMovie.go(DirectorMovie.java:24)
at AccesesPackage.DirectorMovie.main(DirectorMovie.java:13)

Thank you in advance.

My ejb-jar.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd"> 
<ejb-jar>
<display-name>EJB1</display-name>
<enterprise-beans>

<session>
<display-name>AdviceBean</display-name>
<ejb-name>AdviceBean</ejb-name>
<home>headfirst.AdviceHome</home>
<remote>headfirst.Advice</remote>
<ejb-class>headfirst.AdviceBean</ejb-class>
<session-type>Stateless</session-type>
<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
</session>

<session>
<display-name>AdviceStatefullBean</display-name>
<ejb-name>AdviceStatefullBean</ejb-name>
<home>headfirstStatefull.AdviceHomeStatefull</home>
<remote>headfirstStatefull.AdviceStatefull</remote>
<ejb-class>headfirstStatefull.AdviceStatefullBean</ejb-class>
<session-type>Stateful</session-type>
<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
</session>

<entity>
<display-name>MovieBean</display-name>
<ejb-name>MovieBean</ejb-name>
<local-home>movie.MovieHome</local-home>
<local>movie.Movie</local>
<ejb-class>movie.MovieBean</ejb-class>
<persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
<prim-key-class>java.lang.String</prim-key-class>
<reentrant>False</reentrant>
<cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
<abstract-schema-name>moviebean</abstract-schema-name>
<cmp-field><field-name>movieId</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>title</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>genre</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>directorId</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>year</field-name></cmp-field>
<primkey-field>movieId</primkey-field>
<security-identity>
<use-caller-identity></use-caller-identity>
</security-identity>

<query>
<query-method>
<method-name>findByPrimaryKey</method-name>
<method-params>
<method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
</method-params>
</query-method>
<ejb-ql>SELECT OBJECT(m) FROM moviebean m WHERE m.movieId = ?1</ejb-ql>
</query>

</entity>

<entity>
<display-name>DirectorBean</display-name>
<ejb-name>DirectorBean</ejb-name>
<local-home>director.DirectorHome</local-home>
<local>director.Director</local>
<ejb-class>director.DirectorBean</ejb-class>
<persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
<prim-key-class>java.lang.String</prim-key-class>
<reentrant>False</reentrant>
<cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
<abstract-schema-name>directorbean</abstract-schema-name>
<cmp-field><field-name>directorId</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>oscarWinner</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>degrees</field-name></cmp-field>
<cmp-field><field-name>name</field-name></cmp-field>
<primkey-field>directorId</primkey-field>
<security-identity>
<use-caller-identity></use-caller-identity>
</security-identity>

<query>
<query-method>
<method-name>findByPrimaryKey</method-name>
<method-params>
<method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
</method-params>
</query-method>
<ejb-ql>SELECT OBJECT(d) FROM directorbean d WHERE d.directorId = ?1</ejb-ql>
</query>


<query>
<query-method>
<method-name>ejbSelectGetAllMovies</method-name>
<method-params>
<method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
</method-params>
</query-method>
<ejb-ql>SELECT OBJECT(m) FROM moviebean m WHERE m.directorId = ?1</ejb-ql>
</query>

</entity>

</enterprise-beans>


<relationships>
<ejb-relation>
<ejb-relationship-role>
<ejb-relationship-role-name>Director-directs-many-movies</ejb-relationship-role-name>
<multiplicity>One</multiplicity>
<relationship-role-source>
<ejb-name>DirectorBean</ejb-name>
</relationship-role-source>
<cmr-field>
<cmr-field-name>movies</cmr-field-name>
<cmr-field-type>java.util.Collection</cmr-field-type>
</cmr-field>
</ejb-relationship-role>

<ejb-relationship-role>
<ejb-relationship-role-name>Movie-has-one-director-only</ejb-relationship-role-name>
<multiplicity>Many</multiplicity>
<cascade-delete />
<relationship-role-source>
<ejb-name>MovieBean</ejb-name>
</relationship-role-source>
</ejb-relationship-role>
</ejb-relation>
</relationships>
</ejb-jar>
```

My jboss.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 3.2//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_3_2.dtd">
<jboss>
<enterprise-beans>
<session>
<ejb-name>AdviceBean</ejb-name>
<jndi-name>Advisor</jndi-name>
</session>
<session>
<ejb-name>AdviceStatefullBean</ejb-name>
<jndi-name>AdvisorStatefull</jndi-name>
</session>
<entity>
<ejb-name>MovieBean</ejb-name>
<local-jndi-name>movies</local-jndi-name>
</entity>
<entity>
<ejb-name>DirectorBean</ejb-name>
<local-jndi-name>directors</local-jndi-name>
</entity>
</enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

My Director package:

1. Director Bean:

   package director;

   import java.rmi.RemoteException;
   import javax.ejb.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import movie.*;
   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.InitialContext;
   import javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource;
   import javax.sql.PooledConnection;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import AccesesPackage.ConnectionPool;

   public abstract class DirectorBean implements EntityBean {

   ```
   private EntityContext context;


   public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException{
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb activate method");
   }


   public void ejbLoad() throws EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb load method");
   }


   public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException{
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb passivate method");
   }


   public void ejbRemove() throws RemoveException, EJBException{
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb remove method");
   }


   public void ejbStore() throws EJBException{
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb store method");
   }


   public void setEntityContext(EntityContext arg0) throws EJBException{
       this.context = arg0;
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb set entity context method");
   }


   public void unsetEntityContext() throws EJBException{
       System.out.println("Inside director ejb unset entity context method");
   }


   public abstract void setDirectorId(String id);
   public abstract String getDirectorId();
   public abstract void setOscarWinner(boolean b);
   public abstract boolean getOscarWinner();
   public abstract void setDegrees(String m);
   public abstract String getDegrees();
   public abstract void setName(String name);
   public abstract String getName();
   public abstract Collection getMovies();
   public abstract void setMovies(Collection movies);


   public abstract Collection ejbSelectGetAllMovies(String directorId) throws FinderException;


   public String directorName(){
       return this.getName();
   }


   public java.lang.String ejbCreate(String directorId, boolean isOscar, String degrees, String name) throws CreateException {
       this.setDirectorId(directorId);
       this.setOscarWinner(isOscar);
       this.setDegrees(degrees);
       this.setName(name);
       return directorId;
   }


   public void ejbPostCreate(String directorId, boolean isOscar, String degrees, String name) throws CreateException {


   }


   public Collection getAllMovies() {
       Collection coll = null;
       try{
           coll = this.ejbSelectGetAllMovies(this.getDirectorId());
       }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       return coll;
   }


   public void changeOscarStatus(String b){
       Connection con= null;
       try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ejbpr","root","chaitanya");
       String sql1 = "UPDATE director SET degrees = ? where directorId = ?";
       PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
       pstmt.setString(1, b);
       pstmt.setString(2, this.getDirectorId());
       boolean update  = pstmt.execute();
       conn.close();
       System.out.println(update);
       }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Director Home:

   package director;

   import javax.ejb.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public interface DirectorHome extends EJBLocalHome {

   ```
   public Director create(String directorId, boolean isOscar, String degrees, String name) throws CreateException;


   public Director findByPrimaryKey(String directorId) throws FinderException;
   ```

   }
3. Director component interface:

   package director;
   import javax.ejb.*;
   import java.util.*;
   public interface Director extends EJBLocalObject {

   ```
   public void changeOscarStatus(String st);


   public String directorName();


   public Collection getAllMovies();
   ```

   }

My Movie package:

1. Movie Bean:

   package movie;

   import java.rmi.RemoteException;
   import javax.ejb.*;
   import director.*;

   import java.util.*;

   import javax.naming.*;
   import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;

   public abstract class  MovieBean implements EntityBean {

   ```
   private EntityContext context = null;


   public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb activate method");
   }


   public void ejbLoad() throws EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb load method");
   }


   public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb passivate method");
   }


   public void ejbRemove() throws RemoveException, EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb remove method");
   }


   public void ejbStore() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb store method");
   }


   public void setEntityContext(EntityContext arg0) throws EJBException {
       this.context = arg0;
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb set entity context method");
   }


   public void unsetEntityContext() throws EJBException {
       System.out.println("Inside movie ejb unset entity context method");
   }


   public String getMovieTitle(){
       return this.getTitle();
   }


   public String getMovieDirectorId(){
       return this.getDirectorId();
   }


   public String getMovieDirectorName(String directorId){
       String name= null;
       try{
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
       properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
       properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","localhost:1099");
       Context ic = new InitialContext(properties);
       Object d = ic.lookup("directors");
       DirectorHome dir0 = (DirectorHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(d, DirectorHome.class);
       Director direct0 = dir0.findByPrimaryKey(directorId);
       name= direct0.directorName();
       }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}


   return name;


   }


   public abstract String getMovieId();
   public abstract void setMovieId(String movieId);
   public abstract String getTitle();
   public abstract void setTitle(String title);
   public abstract String getYear();
   public abstract void setYear(String year);
   public abstract String getGenre();
   public abstract void setGenre(String genre);
   public abstract void setDirectorId(String directorId);
   public abstract String getDirectorId(); 
   public abstract void setDirector(Director director);
   public abstract Director getDirector();


   public java.lang.String ejbCreate(String movieId, String title, String year, String genre, String directorId) throws CreateException {
       this.setMovieId(movieId);
       this.setTitle(title);
       this.setYear(year);
       this.setGenre(genre);
       this.setDirectorId(directorId);
       return movieId;
   }


   public void ejbPostCreate(String movieId, String title, String year, String genre, String directorId) throws CreateException{   
   }
   ```

   }
2. Movie Home:

   package movie;

   import javax.ejb.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public interface MovieHome extends EJBLocalHome {

   ```
   public Movie create(String movieId, String title, String year, String genre, String directorId) throws CreateException;


   public Movie findByPrimaryKey(String Key) throws FinderException;
   ```

   }
3. Movie component interface:

   package movie;

   import javax.ejb.*;

   public interface Movie extends EJBLocalObject {

   ```
   public String getMovieTitle();


   public String getMovieDirectorName(String directorId);


   public String getMovieDirectorId();
   ```

   }

Finally my client:

```
package AccesesPackage;
import javax.naming.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import javax.rmi.*;
import movie.*;
import director.*;
import javax.ejb.*;

import java.util.*;

public class DirectorMovie {

    //public static final String localJndiName=  "local/"+DirectorBean.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new DirectorMovie().go();
    }

    public void go(){
        try{
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","localhost:1099");
            Context ic = new InitialContext(properties);
            DirectorHome dir0 = (DirectorHome)ic.lookup("directors");
            dir0.findByPrimaryKey("1");

            //DirectorHome dir0 = (DirectorHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(d, DirectorHome.class);
           // Director direct0 = dir0.create("1", true, "3", "Chaitanya");
            //Collection col = direct0.getAllMovies();
            //if(col.isEmpty()){
            //  System.out.println("The returned collection is empty");
            //}
            //else{
            //  Iterator ita = col.iterator();
            //  if (ita.hasNext()){
            //      Movie movieName = (Movie)ita.next();
            //      System.out.println(movieName.getMovieTitle());
            //  }
            //}
            //System.out.println(direct0.directorName());
            //MovieHome mov0 = (MovieHome)ic.lookup("movies");
            //MovieHome mov0 = (MovieHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(m, MovieHome.class);
            //Movie movie0 = mov0.create("M1", "Men In Black", "2001", "Action", "1");
            //System.out.println(movie0.getMovieTitle());
            //String mdId = movie0.getMovieDirectorId();
            //String directorName = movie0.getMovieDirectorName(mdId);
            //System.out.println(directorName);
            //System.out.println();
            }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi above is the detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is **you aren't supposed to define the findByPrimaryKey** in the ejb-jar.xml.

The container *will built it automatically* using your deployment descriptor, the findByPrimaryKey is defined only the Home interface.